# Perl reads textfile just until the first newline

Tags: perl, file-io

I'm trying to read a textfile into variable in perl, but it reads a textfile just until the first newline char.(enter at the end of the sentence)
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use v5.16; 

open(FILE,"<:encoding(UTF-8)", 'data/text.txt') or die "Can't read file [$!]\n";  
chomp(my $document = (<FILE>)); 
close (FILE);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Note, I recommend not putting a newline `\n` at the end of your [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) statement.  That hides the line info for the error.  Alternatively, include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) at the top of your script and error messages will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are by default read line by line, and you have to change [`input record separator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) variable `$/` to `undef` in order to get it into slurp mode,

```
my $document = do { local $/; <FILE> };
```